# How to get organizationId to sisense I am using auth0 with SAML 2?

Tags: integration, saml, auth0, saml-2.0, sisense

I was trying to integrate auth0 with Sisense using SAML 2. I added the two screens while login so that user will first enter the organization name and then user credentials and password.
Now is the issue is I am not able to get the organization name or id in the sisense so that I can use some business logic to show/filter dashboards in sisense using the organizationId.
It would be really helpful if someone can tell me how I can get the organizationId while using SAML 2.
I tried add this action

I tried adding post Login action to get the organizationId and send it using the api.idToken.setCustomClaim and api.accessToken.setCustomClaim methods